# How to get wheel users with specific prefix letters

Tags: sed

```
cat /etc/group | grep wheel
wheel:x:10:I0173203,i04317303,raccount,d454523,c564566,C555533,D2354546
```

I want to extract only the users that start with `c\C i\I d\D`

How do I get this Desired output?

```
I0173203 i04317303 d454523 c564566 C555533 D2354546
```

Comment: What have you tried? And is having the output all on one line part of your specification? Good luck.

Comment: i'm not sure because after i extract the users i will want to use this code for example: For i in $users do ..something with i$... end;

Answer (score 3):

I would use `awk` for this:

```bsh
$ awk -F[:,] '/^wheel/ { 
      for(i=4;i<=NF;i++) if($i~/^[cCiIdD]/) printf "%s%s",$i,(i==NF?RS:OFS)
    }' /etc/group
I0173203 i04317303 d454523 c564566 C555533 D2354546
```

You can also use `perl`:

```bsh
perl -nle '@m=(m/[:,]([iIcCdD]\w+)/g) if $_=~/^wheel/ }{ print "@m"' /etc/group
```

Comment: @jaypal: Now that you also split by `:`, you should start with `i=4` to only match among the usernames.

Comment: I don't think OSX is special in this regard - the format of `/etc/group` is standard on all Unix flavors, I think. The format is: `<groupname>:<password>:<groupid>:<comma-separated-list-of-users>` - see http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcgroup-file/. (The actual password is usually not in the file, and what is printed instead differs by platform; e.g.: OSX: `*`, Linux: `x`.)

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks for the info. In that case your suggestion is absolutely valid and appropriate. Have updated the solution. Thanks! `:)`

Answer (score 2):

```
cat /etc/group | grep wheel | sed 's/^.*:\(.*\)$/\1/g' | sed 's/,/\n/g' | egrep '^[cCiIdD].*'
```

Run first command in chain, look at results. Then add second, look at results, ...

Comment: +1; following @jaypal's example you could eliminate the `cat` and `grep` commands by rewriting the first `sed` command as follows: `sed -n '/^wheel:/ s/^.*:\(.*\)$/\1/gp' /etc/group`. OSX users: Use `sed 's/,/\'$'\n''/g'` as the 2nd `sed` command.

Comment: Thanks, but I intentionally used long chain of simple commands. After all, the whole point is to understand what they do, not just copy-paste solution and then ask the same question again for another file.